# two html onsumbit validation with java

Tags: javascript, html

I have these two java function for validation text input field and drop down selection. I am trying to combine both validation onSubmit. it didn't work when I put both validation together but it work when I put one at the time.

```
 function validname(fld) {
 var error = "";
 var valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$/; 

 if (fld.value == "") {
    fld.style.borderColor = '#ff0000'; 
    document.getElementById('name').style.color = "#ff0000";
    error = " - Invalid device name..\n";
 } else if(valid.test(fld.value)){
    fld.style.borderColor = ''; 
    document.getElementById('name').style.color = "#000000";
 } else {
    fld.style.borderColor = '#ff0000'; 
    document.getElementById('name').style.color = "#ff0000";
    error = " - Invalid device name. \n";
 }
 return error;
  }

  function ValidateDropForm() {
    var isValidDropForm = true;
    var errorMessages = "";

    var e = document.getElementById('domain');
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].text == "--Select--") {
        document.getElementById('domainError').innerHTML = "- Domain name required.";
        isValidDropForm = false;
    } 
   if (!isValidDropForm) {
        //alert(errorMessages);

    }

     return isValidDropForm;
    }
```

this what I did..

HTML
      `<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm(this) && ValidateDropForm()">`

Comment: how can it be java? its javascript!!

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing in a function

```
onsubmit="validate(this)"
```

Or

```
onsubmit="function () { return validateForm(this) && ValidateDropForm(); }"
```

I highly recommend the former